# block specific string with iptables rules

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I want to block a strings with iptables rule, but i want to know the best way to do it.

For example, i have this 4 rules:

```
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p all -m string --hex-string "|some_string|" --algo kmp -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p all -m string --hex-string "|some_string|" --algo kmp -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -p all -m string --hex-string "|some_string|" --algo kmp -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p all -m string --hex-string "|some_string|" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

Note: "|some_string|" it would be replaced by some real string

**The question:**

If I use the MANGLE rule, is that enough? (I do not need to use the other rules, or I must use all of them)

thanks in advance

Comment: To what traffic do you want to apply this rule?

Comment: to all the traffic on my local network (which passes through a linux proxy server - man in the middle)

Comment: "To all the traffic"? If it is HTTPS or SSH how do you think you will be able to see inside the encrypted packets?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek With "all traffic" i mean all traffic, where iptables rules can "see" the string.

Comment: Ok so "all traffic with content in clear" then  which is a substring of "all traffic". You are still too vague on too many points. Example: one might want/think it wants to filter DNS queries. Checking a "string" inside a DNS packet is far more complicated (because of name compression in this protocol) than what a single match string match rule can do.

Comment: 443 is clear traffic for you? I really think your goals need to be more detailed as the reality does not seem to be aligned with what you need/want.  Whatever filtering you want to put in place, you need to understand how people will get around it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek This is what happens with HTTPS communication in a browser: you used to say "Hello" and the information was transmitted in a "visible" way to everyone through the HTTP protocol. The secure HTTPS protocol precisely converts the communication channel into a secure and encrypted channel, but that "Hello" is still transmitted in plain text. And it is this "Hello" that I capture the hex string to put it in the iptables rule. It is therefore irrelevant whether the communication is encrypted or not

Comment: Either your setup is not clear or you are not understanding HTTPS correctly. If your host is a level 3 or 4 gateway/forwarded 443 (HTTPS) traffic will be completely opaque/undecipherable to it and you will never say any plain text inside it . You could **only** see it if  it was a level 7 proxy that terminates the TLS stream.